# Functions not being inlined with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, inline

I'm compiling the next simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct PP
{
    inline void wInline();
}

inline void PP::wInline()
{
    std::cout << "hola" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    PP pp;
    pp.wInline();
    return 0;
}
```

in this way:

```
g++ -O0 -finline-functions -finline-functions-called-once
-finline-small-functions -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -Winline
main.cpp
```

with gcc 4.8.2 and wInline is not being inlined.

Are the -finline-functions, -finline-functions-called-once and
-finline-small-functions flags enough?
Why am I having no warnings even with the -Winline flag enabled?

Comment: What does PP stand for? /just curious

Comment: Please use your editor and browser's copy and paste facilities instead of re-typing. It would be nice to have code that actually compiles. You did clearly make an attempt at creating a short self-contained testcase, thank you for that, just make it a valid one. :)

Comment: Why do you think the function is not inlined?  Can you show the assembly?

Answer (score 1):

The `inline` keyword is a hint to the optimizer. Since you are compiling with `-O0`, no optimization is done.

The [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says this about `-Winline`:

> Warn if a function that is declared as inline cannot be inlined.

There are rules for what functions can be declared `inline` as well as heuristics that gcc uses to decide if it should inline a function declared as inline.

You can read more about the `inline` keyword [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).

(Edited to answer second question.)

Comment: You didn't answer the OP's second question, why `-Winline` doesn't warn about this. The documentation doesn't say anything about optimisations needing to be enabled to get warnings for that. Do you want to add something about it to your answer?

Comment: I don't think the `inline` keyword is not intended to be a hint.  It means the _code_ is inline (in the source), not that the assembly should be inlined.

Comment: It means exactly that the generated machine code should be written where a function call would be used otherwise. Read the links I've added to the answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's exactly what it means. See [dcl.fct.spec]p2, which contains "The inline specifier indicates to the implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the point of call is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism." It goes on to say implementations are not required to pay attention to that hint, but the intent really is inlining the function body.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano You added a quote of the documentation, but the documentation doesn't answer the OP's second question, in fact it strongly implies the opposite, that the OP *should* get a warning.

Comment: As I see it, since optimizations are off, all `inline` keywords are ignored. The warning should be emitted when the `inline` rules are broken or the heuristics say not to inline the function for whatever reason. As I see it.